# Understanding the type of the following function

Tags: types, ocaml

I wrote a merge_sorted function in OCaml, which takes a comparison function and two sorted lists and merges them together. I am trying to understand why the type of this function is

```
('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list
```

and not

```
('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a list
```

since it just returns a list. Below is my code for the merge_sorted function

```
let rec merge_sorted lt a b = 
    match a with 
    | [] -> b
    | h::t -> match b with
            | []-> a 
            | hh::tt -> if (lt h hh) 
                        then h::merge_sorted lt t b 
                        else hh::merge_sorted lt a tt;;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function takes three arguments of types `'a -> 'a -> bool`, `'a list`, and `'a list`. It returns a value of type `'a list`. The type of a function (when defined in curried form as yours is) consists of the argument types, separated by `->`, followed by the return type.

Thus the type really is `('a -> 'a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list -> 'a list`. The first two `'a list`s are the second and third argument types. The last `'a list` is the return type.

This isn't just a notational convention. Your function actually accepts a comparison function (of type `'a -> 'a -> bool`) and returns a function of two arguments. The returned function accepts a list (of type `'a list`) and returns a function. And so on.